# Satisfiability Toward A Sequential Circuit

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, circuits

Define a sequential circuit model be a directed graph with each vertices being a boolean gate. The difference is that we allow cycles in the boolean circuit. Each cycle will determine a boolean equation.

For example, constructing a loop by connecting the input and output of a negation gate will yield the equation $x=\lnot x$, which is not satisfiable. Given such circuit, the "satisfiability" in the sense naturally occur. My question is:

> Is determining whether this circuit can be satisfied known to be hard or easy? Furthermore, is finding or enumerating these configuration known to be hard or easy?

Comment: Have you tried reducing SAT to your problem?

Comment: Oh indeed, I just find it to be NP-hard.
Reduction is by adding a xor loop to examine the circuit. Namely,
$y=y\otimes \lnot A(x)$.

Comment: On the other hand, is it NP-complete?

Comment: Well, is it in NP? Can you verify a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, since number of cycles is exponentially bounded. But I guess we can use the fact that rank of its cycle space is polynomially bounded, namely $O(n^2)$. The problem is I do not know if its possible to lift the boolean space to our circuit equations, (not even linear).

Comment: If I give you a truth assignment to the gates, can you check whether it satisfies all equations?

Comment: Not sure if we have this property. If the two equation is satisfied, then the equation of their cycle addition  will also be satisfied??

Comment: Perhaps you should formulate more clearly what it means for an assignment to satisfy a circuit, since the way I see it, you just need to check all the gate equations – nothing about cycles.

Comment: hang on, I uderstand what you are saying. Indeed checking all gate equation will suffice

Comment: Now you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

OK so now I figured this out. The problem is $NP$-complete. We could simply verify an assignment by checking each gate as an equation. For solving SAT of boolean function A(x), simply construct a equation, $y=y\otimes\lnot A(x)$ would suffice.